# Determine which JS function applied a certain style with Chrome

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome-devtools

Is there a way I can determine which JQuery function applied a certain style with Chrome Dev Tools?

For example:

[image]

I have this markup in the Elements tab of Chrome dev tools:

As you can see, it has an inline style of `display:none;` Is there a way to determine which function applied this style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `Attributes modifications`

`Attributes modifications: Triggered when an attribute is added or removed on the currently selected node, or when an attribute value changes.`

To break on all inline style changes using the Elements panel context menu's Break on -> Attributes modifications.

See: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/breakpoints/add-breakpoints?hl=en - `Set a breakpoint on DOM change`

Comment: thanks dude, you're a life saver. I only got function from jquery.js that applied the style (`showHide(elements,show);`), it was enough to search the rest of my code for snippets that called this function so I found it eventually. EDIT: Callstack trace from dev tools is an even better way than manually searching. :)